# RangeValidator Type Double MaximumValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

this a portion of my code, i need to prevent users to enter other then number (Double) with three digit after comma or point.

i need to fix the MaximumValue = "100.000" and the MinimumValue = "0.001"

from the code behind

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPoidsTot_Colct"  runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
 runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPoidsTot_Colct" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Poids Non Valide !" 
SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{1,3}([,.][0-9]{1,3})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValdPoids" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Non Valide !"  ControlToValidate="txtPoidsTot_Colct" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Type="Double"   CultureInvariantValues="true"/>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!00)(?:\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,3}|100[.,]0{1,3})$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/53

Comment: i need to fix the MaximumValue = "100.000" and the MinimumValue = "0.001" of the RangeValidator from code behind

Comment: @AymenRM this regex will only allow values between the range you gave.isnt that wht you want

Comment: range have to fixed in code behind because i get them from a databse

Comment: @AymenRM then why is this tagged `regex`?Do you need to change it?